# Uploaded PDF text looks blurry on my blog

Tags: images, text, pdf

I've created a PDF pricelist for my photography clients, and it looks great as a PDF. However, I wanted to upload it to my blogsite as an image for visual impact.

The steps I took are:

1. Imported PDF into CS5. Options I chose are Anti-aliased, Resolution 300, Mode RGB, Bit Depth 16.
2. I changed the image size to 920 pixels for my blog.
3. I saved for web as a png with highest quality possible.
4. I uploaded and inserted to a blog post.

Strangely, in my preview screen the PNG image looks great! But when I view it in a web page, the text is quite blurry and looks terrible. Also, there is a direct link at the bottom of the post to the PDF and it looks great.

I would love any advice you have on uploading images with text to the web. I really don't want to re-create the info on my PDF into an actual image, but maybe that's what I need to do... Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So, Before uploading it looks good? To me it sounds like wordpress resized the image when you uploaded it.

Comment: by the way, it's à la carte, not al a carte. :)

Comment: @amber prior Your website has been hacked. There is obfuscated javascript at the bottom of the page that attempts an attack on any visitor. I've disabled the link. When you have the problem fixed, you can edit the question to restore it.

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum, thanks for the tip on al a carte. Where do you see it without the apostrophe? I thought I changed everything. :) \@Alan, goodness sorry! Thank you for calling that to my attention. Do you know how I can remove it? Wordpress completely frustrates me with images (and hacks apparently!) I'm ready to find another platform. Thanks to everyone for your help! :)

Comment: @e100, how do I prevent the image from being scaled?

Comment: When you say "my preview screen", are you talking about the Save For Web preview in Photoshop?  If so, are you certain you are on the "Optimized" tab and not "Original"?

Comment: @AmberPrior: It's not an apostrophe; it's an accent grave. :) On your second pricing page, in the frame on the left immediately under Prints and Pricing, it says *Prints al a carte*. The translation of *à la carte* is "on the cart," meaning "one at a time." So it's "à" *on* "la" *the* "carte."

Comment: Thanks Lauren. I remember something about it in French class but I appreciate your help. I hope I've got it right now. :)

Comment: @Farray- I mean my blog post preview screen. :) I always save for web in PS - I usually view the options in 4-up view so I can compare quality, but I believe it is still optimized.

Comment: Wow thanks everyone for your help!! I'm not sure why, but 911 pixels seems to be the trick! Also, I made sure that I was in the "optimized" screen in Save for Web & Devices. Thank you thank you for all your advice. :)

Comment: @amberprior Glad to hear the problem got resolved.  StackExchange doesn't operate like a traditional forum, it's really geared towards Q&A.  To that end, you are encouraged to up-vote answers that helped you and click the checkmark beside the post that answered your question.  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum: On the cart? It translates "as per the menu", but yes it refers to items ordered individually, rather than a fixed set.

Comment: @e100: Yes, you are correct -- the "individual ordering" is what I was aiming for. Got too focused on the accent and missed the translation. :)

Answer (score 2):

i don't think you need to recreate the info on your PDF to an actual image. Try saving your png/jpg of your price list, etc. as 911 pixels wide. You can also try saving it/them as 72 resolution.

Comment: Why 911 pixels? Just curious. :)

Comment: @amberprior: The content area on your site is 915 pixels wide, so anything less than that _should_ work.

Comment: Guess WP itself, or the particular theme being used, scales images wider than the content area.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the image is fine but it's being scaled up or down slightly on the web page.

You should be able to confirm this by comparing the image as shown on the page against the image alone (Firefox: right click the image on the page > View image; otherwise get the image's URL in the browser address bar).

If the bare image looks OK, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to make sure your browser isn't zoomed? Make sure it's not some problem with just your system.

Another issue to research of is pixel snapping and the anti-aliasing methods for text.